# Copy dialog "formatting selection" is freezing, causing the GUI to hang, how to turn it off?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just updated Visual Studio 2015 professional with update 2 and when I am copying or even highlighting something in code an anoying popup comes with a cancel button and takes about 1-5 seconds and makes the whole thing freeze.  It comes up as I am selecting/copying one word or many lines of code.  How do I turn this off until Microsoft fixes whatever this is...[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and installed [Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs), which seems to have corrected it.

Comment: Hmm... The about page says 2015 Update 3 and I'm still seeing this issue.   It seems like it happens when I have a SQL query window open and I'm querying a database.

Comment: These are the versions from the About VS page: Do these match yours?
[MS VS Comm 2015, Update 3, Version 14.0.25431.01]
[SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61021.0]

Comment: Sorry @Sean, I have the Pro version. MS VS Pro 2015 Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3, SSDT 14.0.60525.0, among many other installed products.

Comment: Im experiencing this in vs2017

Answer (score 5):

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and still have the issue mentioned above.
This manifests itself, in a GUI dialogue saying "Copying from...." or "Pasting.." when doing simple copy and paste operations.

I found that the issue was related to **CodeLens**, some update has just come out which interferes with this. I will investigate and put my findings here.

Other things that can also affect this are:

1) Network related issues, if you network is slow or dropping packets I found my GUI would lock up with no noticeable traces (Task Manager, Resource Monitor)

2) Signing into Visual Studio from within VS 2015, my account had got into a bad state for some reason and lost the credentials. This was not obvious and in the background something must have been trying over and over again, causing the GUI to lock up but also, anytime I worked on a new file it would hang for 3-5 seconds. I signed out and everything started to work normally.

3) Hardware acceleration in Visual Studio enabled (it is by default) and video drivers misbehaving.

Comment: Disabling codelens seems to have solved the problem. I might also have a choppy net connection leading to this.

Comment: @OmkarKhair is this a recent issue for you, what version of windows are you running? Any anti virus?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 with updated Bit Defender and security patches. I later enabled codelens, and disabled only Application insight details in codelens. It has been working well for me since then.

Comment: I've enabled  codeLens again with default options, I will let you know how I go.

Comment: The issue has resolved itself. I'm not 100% what solved it, it could have been a Windows update to my Anti Virus software or some other Windows update since I wrote this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug that may have been made worse with the last update, I didn't have it until Update 2 but some reports exist pre-update2.

It seems to happen only on big files so you might try taking the time to split them, courtesy of Microsoft :<>

[MSDN Link to report](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e334f767-32a9-40e6-8765-d95647a80d21/copy-and-paste-vs-2015?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Answer (score 0):

I just found that if you try to copy and this dialog comes up you can just hit cancel. It still copies the text then you can continue and paste. Basically  you don't have to wait until it's done or the dialog closes.

Comment: I clicked cancel and the dialog went away but then the IDE was just frozen with the busy spinner.