# Disable formatting on Copy in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a project which has quite large files, ~55000 lines per file. (don't ask why)

Well, anytime I try to copy (!! Not paste !!) a part of text in a `.CS` file, I'm getting a dialog box saying `Formatting` which stays for 3-5 seconds. Is getting pretty frustrating.

Is there an option to disable this?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727108/new-copy-dialog-formatting-selection-is-very-annoying-how-to-turn-it-off

Answer (score 10):

You may disable through the following:

> `Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> "Automatically format on paste"`

(You can typically find the "*Options*" button under the "*Tools*" and/or "*Debug*" menu depending on your user interface configurations)

This will improve performance a bit. But, it is known bug after the last update and you won't be able to copy immediately.

Comment: After Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, it is not an issue anymore. Related Link : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

Comment: still seeing this in VS2017, the solution is appreciated

Comment: @neogeek for VS2017, Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> General (then uncheck everything there).

Answer (score 6):

ilkerkaran's solution didn't work for me, so I kept Googling and found out this is part of the Productivity Power Tools extension. Far from increasing my productivity, it prevented me from copy/pasting my code entirely!

Here's the solution I found:

Go to **Extensions** > **Manage Extensions** > **Search** for `HTML` > **Copy As HTML** > **Disable**

Then, restart Visual Studio. It seems to have fixed this problem for me after YEARS of dealing with this thinking there was no solution after the above solution didn't work!

(this is a link to what clued me in: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/251912/htmlcopy-formatting-document-for-copying.html)

This answer is specific to **Visual Studio Community 2019**, your mileage may vary.

Note: This precludes the need to turn off format on paste, which is a feature I quite like.

Comment: thank you, this helped me. Best search in the installed Extensions, so you actually get to the option to disable it.